# Make font same size across PDF tables

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, latex

I am putting multiple tables into my InDesign document, created in PDF format (using LaTex). The PDF are not rasterized. When I change the size of the frame, and rescale the graphic, the relative size of the font changes. How to I keep the same font size across all of my tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InDesign treats linked/placed PDFs as if they are images.

You simply **can not** scale one aspect of a placed PDF while not scaling another.

Placed PDFs are seen as **one** object. 
Any type within the PDF is **not** recognized as live type by InDesign.

If you want type sizes to remain consistent, you need to set your tables up in InDesign rather than linking to PDFs. Or, scale **all** the placed PDFs the same amount.

I'm not a Latex user, but you may be able to copy/paste the table text from Latex to InDesign and then configure table styles within InDesign to make the transition a relatively quick thing after the first table. This is often what I do when given Excel tables for use.